# DISTINCT value from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetIdleCustomerlist](
@num_months Int
)

AS
BEGIN

SELECT DISTINCT
    cust.cust_code as cust_code ,
    cust.name as cust_name,
    MAX (invoice.created_date) as Last_invoice_date             

    FROM [dbo].[customer] cust LEFT JOIN  [dbo].[crm_invoice_header] invoice on cust.cust_code = invoice.cust_code

    GROUP BY cust.cust_code ,cust.name,invoice.created_date

    HAVING (( MAX (invoice.created_date)< DATEADD(MONTH, -@num_months ,GETDATE())) OR invoice.created_date IS NULL)

    ORDER BY CAST (cust.cust_code AS int) ASC

END
```

I want to remove duplicate customers code, but DISTINCT keyword gives me this error.

Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetIdleCustomerlist, Line 21
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this version of the query:

```
SELECT cust.cust_code as cust_code, cust.name as cust_name,
      MAX(invoice.created_date) as Last_invoice_date             
FROM [dbo].[customer] cust LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[crm_invoice_header] invoice
     on cust.cust_code = invoice.cust_code
GROUP BY cust.cust_code, cust.name
HAVING (( MAX (invoice.created_date) < DATEADD(MONTH, -@num_months, GETDATE())) OR MAX(invoice.created_date) IS NULL)
ORDER BY CAST(cust.cust_code AS int) ASC;
```

The `distinct` shouldn't be necessary and you need to remove the date from the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: when remove the date, it gives me the error

"Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Column 'dbo.crm_invoice_header.created_date' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: @Amila . . . You just need to use `MAX(invoice.created_date)`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `DISTINCT` and remove `invoice.created_date` in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    cust.cust_code AS cust_code,
    cust.name AS cust_name,
    MAX(invoice.created_date) AS Last_invoice_date      
FROM dbo.customer cust
LEFT JOIN dbo.crm_invoice_header invoice
    ON cust.cust_code = invoice.cust_code
WHERE
    invoice.created_date < DATEADD(MONTH, -@num_months, GETDATE())
    OR invoice.created_date IS NULL
GROUP BY
    cust.cust_code, cust.name
ORDER BY
    ORDER BY CAST(cust.cust_code AS INT)
```

You can also move the conditions in the `HAVING` to `WHERE`